# OpenSSL trouble python

Tags: python, windows, openssl, web.py, m2crypto

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server) to get a little MDM test setup going.

I have the [server](https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server#server-setup) set up and working on Ubuntu but when I try to run it on windows, I get the following error:

Code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Starting Server" 
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.internalerror = web.debugerror

    try:
        app.run()
    except Exception, e:

        print "{0}".format(e)
        sys.exit(0)
else:
    # app.run() seems to use server.py as a module
    # Placing these in main causes them not to run
    # Placing these above main causes them to run twice
    mdm_commands = setup_commands()
    read_devices()
```

Error:

```
Starting Server
https://0.0.0.0:8080/
[('system library', 'fopen', 'No such file or directory'), ('BIO routines', 'FIL
E_CTRL', 'system lib'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file', 'system
 lib')]
```

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a missing `Server.crt` file in the project directory.